# IF AND statements in AWS Quicksight

Tags: if-statement, data-analysis, analysis, amazon-quicksight

I have survey data and I want to create a calculated field based on participants answers to multiple questions. Each question is a field.

I have tried this formula using ifelse with no luck:

`ifelse({Question1} = "Yes" AND {Question2} = "Yes" AND {Question3} = "Yes" AND {Question4} = "No"), "Yes", "No”)`